# Chainsaw doesn't work on localhost

Tags: logging, udp, nlog, apache-chainsaw

I use Log2Console to view remote logs. My logger is NLog. My config looks like this:

```
<target name="log_main" xsi:type="Chainsaw"
        address="udp://localhost:12345"/>
```

When I run both logs producer and Log2Console on a single machine, no logs are shown. When I run them on different machines (specifying corresponding address, of course), everything works fine.

I've tried replacing `127.0.0.1` with `127.0.0.2` or `localhost`. Also I've tried enabling/disabling IPv6 in Log2Console, but it still doesn't work.
My system is Win7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem whit UDP. When I've tried TCP I got "invalid stream header: 3C6C6F67" exception. Didn't find solution, but I've swiched to Log2Console (http://log2console.codeplex.com/). You can use same `xsi:type="Chainsaw"` target.
It's simpler but powerfull enough for me. Also it works whit NLog seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. TCP or UDP didn't matter, but when I specified the full IP address for the local machine, it worked.

Comment: this worked for me. It had to be the numeric IP address, host name or localhost did not work either